# how to make changes in properties in java frame appear when you export project to zip file

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, export

I made a project in java by javaFrame and I modified the properties of the objects(like font color and font format for a button for example) and I also added images not by code source instead I did it by design tool for a label. but the problem is that when I export the project to my teacher it was without design and the images do not exist. not that I put the images in a folder in the project and I exported the project as zip file.
is there is a method to make the changes appear in source code? not only in my lap?

Comment: Best guess. The code is trying to load resources using `File`. Resources in a Jar must be accessed by `URL`. Show code for anything better than guesses.

Comment: actually, when I modify anything in design mode, everything is written directly in source code, but when I export this project to anyone it doesn't appear many changes like font design and images , I don't think image and format need jar because it is normally in java library.  if I have to upload it in URL how can I do that, please?

Comment: Application resources will become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  An [tag:embedded-resource] must be accessed by URL rather than file.  See the [info. page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL.

Comment: .. did you solve the problem(s)? If so, you might enter an answer below. Either way you can delete the question using the Delete link towards the left, between the question (above) and these comments (below) it.